# Inserting PHP foreach array into mysql with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, prepared-statement, sql-insert

Here's my dilemma, I'm at a loss.  I'm trying to add multiple values from an array into a database by looping through them with a prepared mysql statement:

- If I "execute" the statement within the foreach loop it only adds the
  **last entry** from the array.
- If I "execute" it outside of the loop it inserts **3 individual rows** to the database.  I would like all columns filled out under one created now() date and row.
- If I prepare the $stmt before the foreach loop, then it errors undefined variable. So I've put it after defining in the loop, even though in w3schools it shows that you can define the "bind_param" variables prior to setting parameters, which I don't understand either. Thanks!

  ```
  foreach ($products as $v) {
      $product_was = $v['name'];
      $product_now = $v['name'];
      $was = $v['was'];
      $now = $v['now'];

      $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO $table_name (date_created, $product_was, $product_now) VALUES (now(), ?, ?)");

      $stmt->bind_param("ss", $was, $now);
      $stmt->execute();
  }
  $stmt->close();
  $conn->close();
  ```

Comment: what does your table look like?

Comment: you have twice the same column-name, that doesn't seem right? (`$product_was` and `$pruduct_now` are the same: `$v['name']`)

Comment: Do the table name and field names really change for each product?

Comment: My table name is fixed, so one table.  But I have different columns for different products. I then have split each product into 2 columns, "product name _was" and "product name _now" column for each.  The only reason I've done this is I'm trying to store the prices of some products on a daily basis, so it's not like one product has one price.  It will have many prices recurring. My code puts the prices in the correct columns as desired, so 'name' is working for me, this is slightly simplified above, but it's the order and positioning to get it to bind in one go for one row!?

Comment: The `prepare()` and `bind_param()` methids should be written before the loop.  The only thing to do inside of the loop is to update the variables to be bound and call the `execute()` method.